# Mongoose populate

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

```
var estadoSchema = Schema({
    estado_nome: String
});

var cidadeSchema = Schema({
    cidade_nome: String,
    estado_reference: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Estados'}]
});
```

this are design schemas, and below the inclusion in the database, I have problem related to schema state that repeating at insertion time, the ideal would be to create a schma state only if it does not exist, and associate the schema city the state by reference. Following the creation of schemas.

```
Estado.create(req.body)
          .then(function(estado){
                Cidade.create({cidade_nome: cidade, cidade_reference: [estado._id]})
                      .then(function(cidade){
                            res.status(201).json(cidade);
                      }, function(erro){
                            res.status.json(erro)
                      });  
                res.status(201).json(estado);
          }, function(erro){
                res.status.json(erro)
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `unique : true` in your `estado_nome` in `estadoSchema` . This will make sure that new state is created only if it doesn't exist, and there are no duplicates.

```
var estadoSchema = Schema({
    estado_nome: {
        type :String,
        unique : true
    }
});
```